# Что делает данный кусок кода? $("#table",$(".someth"))

Tags: javascript, jquery

Попался возник вопрос в собеседовании: что делает этот кусок кода

```
$("#table",$(".someth"))
```

На мой взгляд - это бред, с помощью поиска и документации так же не смог найти.

Comment: Получил ответ: да, это действительно задумывался как контекст селектора, но с ошибкой (спрятали в большом полотне jQuery цепочек).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно документации второй параметр - контекст селектора. То есть выполняется как бы подзапрос. Этот вызов аналогичен

```
$(".someth").find("#table");
```

Соответсвенно будут найдены все элементы с классом `someth` и, затем, внутри них элементы c `id` равным `table`.

[Страница документации](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) (по-английски); [Описание по-русски](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_jQuery).

Comment: И всё-таки, элемент с id. Даже если их реально несколько, найдётся только один. Это такая фича для селектора, состоящего только из id.

Comment: @Qwertiy, прошу прощения за занудство, но в данном контексте все-таки элементы. Если бы было несколько элементов с таким id то `$("#table").length` возвращало бы `1`, а вот `$("#table", $(".someth"))` возьмет по одному элементу из каждого элемента контекста. См. http://jsfiddle.net/hzLj4qox/1/

Comment: Хм.. Пожалуй, да - по одному элементу для каждого контекста.

Comment: @Qwertiy, кстати спасибо за наводку. Не знал, что если таких элементов будет несколько jQuery выберет только один. Как-то не пригождалось. Обычно всегда `id` - уникальный и вообще из JS чаще работаю с классами.

Comment: можно применять для каждого, если обернуть .each()

Answer (score 0):

Пример [группового селектор](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)а, возвращает набор из элементов, которые удовлетворяют одному из селекторов

Comment: Запятая не внутри. Второй аргумент - jQuery-набор. Так что мимо.

Comment: Да, все ок, эта была спрятанная ошибка в коде.